# changing a table to array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a temp table which I fill and clear it in a loop in my code.
becouse of using database, it takes musch time. I want to change it to an array to run my app quicker.
here is my table columns:

```
ID ( int) , Type (string ), Amount (int)
```

**reson** : I have a loop which is repeated 700 times! I have some tables tu have store my data. now I finished my project and I just need one of those tables & the others are useless. I want to optimize my code to run it quicker.
THANKS.

Comment: Why do suspect you will get a speedbump filling an array instead of table from a DB? Can you post some code so can maybe spot problems. Btw how long does it take? Much time can be 1sec to a couple of years.

Comment: What's the problem in reading the data and save it in array via loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET 4.0, you can use a generic list of a generic `Tuple` class:

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<int,string,int>>();
```